# NDK program killed by SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-ndk

I write a simple NDK program that has a logger that runs in another thread.

My program runs successfully but after that the programs quits and sometimes it dosen't quits after running my c++ code and works correctly.
Anyone knows why my program quit after running the code.

when I use strace to debug my program it tells me +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++

```
semget(0x1c, 0xbe9222e8, 0x10, 0xffffffff) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
msgget(0x1, 0xbe922430, 0x418fce8c, 0xa8121b40) = 0
semget(0x1c, 0xbe9222e8, 0x10, 0xffffffff) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSTOP (Stopped (signal)) @ 0 (0) ---
msgget(0x1, 0xbe922430, 0x418fce8c, 0xa8121b40) = 0
semget(0x1c, 0xbe9222e8, 0x10, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

If I disabled the thread everything works fine maybe Logging in another thread with logcat is not safe

Comment: It looks as though your c++ code is committing a segfault, but there are many causes for this, which are not easy to spot without further information and examples of your code.  It could easily be that you just need to ensure your logger thread has stopped and is destroyed **before** the main program exits, otherwise it may be internally referencing some memory that no longer is valid to reference, i.e. the main thread is gone, and the OS now segfaults the logger when it attempts to access some of this memory.  However, without code and further information, this is difficult to know for sure.

Comment: @waxspin: Thanks for your reply. I link to my codes here. I hope you can help me. [thread](http://kge.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/kge/trunk/engine/KGEmain/KgeThread.cpp?revision=613&view=markup) [logger](http://kge.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/kge/trunk/engine/KGEmain/Logger.cpp?revision=609&view=markup) [my test code](http://kge.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/kge/trunk/tests/01%20Logger%20test/main.cpp?revision=606&view=markup) my project is cross platform see the code with KGE_PLATFORM_ANDROID preprocessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@waxspin
You were right my program exits before my logger thread destroyed.